# Compactness in the Flat Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is folkloric, at least at my stage of learning, that the flat (fppf) and etale topologies on varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ are "like" the complex topology. My question concerns how far we can push this analogy.

For example, it is common to single out projective varieties as the "compact" ones, although of course anything reasonable is compact in the Zariski topology. So if the analogies have legs, there should be results along the lines of "a quasi-projective variety is projective if and only if every fppf cover has a finite subcover." Is there anything of this sort? Or if not, where is the analogy breaking down?

Comment: It appears to me that every fppf cover of an affine scheme has a finite subcover. So that won't work. The right notion of compactness is already captured in the Zariski topology, via properness.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not bemoaning the lack of a good notion for compactness in algebraic geometry. I'm just wondering whether the idea of "like the complex topology" extends beyond just the fact that you allow smaller open sets.

Comment: The fppf topology doesn't really have "smaller open sets". In some sense they are "larger" – after all, the whole point is to allow non-injective morphisms to be neighbourhoods.

Comment: To clarify what Zhen Lin is saying, if you want to define 'subcover' as meaning a subset $\{V_j\}\subseteq\{U_i\}$ such that the images of $V_j$ cover $X$, then you always get a finite subcover if your object is qc. Indeed, the image of each $U_i$ is open (since the mapping is fppf), and so just take finitely many of the $U_i$'s that cover it. So, this is not going to give you any sort of useful notion of compactness. I think the problem is, and these words will probably make @ZhenLin happy :). It's not really the sites $X_\mathrm{et}$ and $X^\mathrm{an}_\mathrm{et}$ that are equivalent, but

Comment: their associated topoi (their category of sheaves). So the properties that one understand better topologically are those which can be phrased sheaf theoretically. For example, we have a better notion of 'higher connectedness' since this is some sort of cohomological notion, which can be gotten at sheaf theoretically. The notion of compactness is not such a notion, as far as I can tell. Maybe @ZhenLin or somebody else will have a comment against this though.

Comment: As far as I know, the topos associated with an analytic space is the topos associated with the underlying topological space. So it's not equivalent to the étale topos of a scheme (which is rarely equivalent to a topos coming from a topological space).